# How do I have 5 divs fadein, fadeout and stop on the last one?

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for each div to fadein, display for 5 seconds, fadeout. However on the last one I'm looking for it to stop (not loop) as the user will be able to navigate the content.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you begin with this?

Comment: It would help to show your code or create a jsfiddle to demonstrate your problem http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: The code below does what I want with images. I need it to do work with divs instead and not loop on the last one or redirect.
    
    <script>
    $(function() {
  
    var images = $('.slideshow'), len = images.length;

    images.each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*9000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
    $(this).delay(7000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
         if (i === len - 1) window.location = 'www.google.com';           
     });
    });
    });
  
    });
    </script>

Comment: @Scott Did my answer helped you in anyway?

Comment: @freebird I figured it out using <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
         $('.one').fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
         $('.two').delay(8500).fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
         $('.three').delay(16500).fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
         $('.four').delay(24500).fadeIn(1500).delay(5000).fadeOut(1500);
         $('.five').delay(32500).fadeIn(1500);
         });
      </script>

Comment: @Scott Why not use .each() function for looping through the divs?

Comment: @freebird I want to have control over each one because the timing may change or be unique for each one. I don't want the last one fading out either. This works perfectly though.

Comment: @Scott Ok hope I was able to contribute to your problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be pretty straightforward - use these:

- `fadeIn()` - http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- `fadeOut()` - http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- `delay()` - http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Just make a sequence of events that is triggered by on page load, or whatever event you want.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new at making this stuff from scratch, however I just figured it out with those 3 functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through all your `divs` using `jquery` `.each()` function and then `fadein` each `div` with a delay of 5 seconds and then `fadeout`.If the `div` is last then prevent `fadeout`.

Here is what I came up with

```
$('#container div').each(function(index){
$(this).fadeIn("fast", function() {

    if(index!=4)
    $(this).delay(5000).fadeOut("slow");


});
});
```

**[See Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DC2VH/)**

​